# How to pass event handlers to React-node in React-Recompose App

Tags: reactjs, ref, recompose

Got working App at: https://github.com/BeerDRinker/recompose-ref

Following code(commented part in /src/App.js) works as expected:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.node = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
        value: 1
    };
}

handleTouchStart = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + 1 });
};

handleTouchEnd = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value - 1 });
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.node.current.ontouchstart = this.handleTouchStart;
    this.node.current.ontouchend = this.handleTouchEnd;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Value: {this.state.value}</h3>
            <button ref={this.node}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;
```

But I need the same functionality by using Recompose. I tried, but got nothing working. My code sample(not commented part in /src/App.js) that don't works:

```
import React from "react";
    import {
        compose,
        lifecycle,
        setDisplayName,
        withProps,
       withStateHandlers
} from "recompose";

import "./App.css";

const state = {
    value: 1
};

const stateHandlers = {
    handleTouchStart: value => () => ({
        value: value + 1
    }),
    handleTouchEnd: value => () => ({
        value: value - 1
    })
};

export const enhance = compose(
    setDisplayName("App"),
    withProps(props => ({
        bookNode: React.createRef()
    })),
    withStateHandlers(state, stateHandlers),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            this.bookNode.current.ontouchstart =   
            this.handleTouchStart;
            this.bookNode.current.ontouchend = this.handleTouchEnd;
        }
    })
);

export const App = ({ value, bookNode }) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Value: {value}</h3>
        <button ref={bookNode}>Submit</button>
    </div>
);

export default enhance(App);
```

Just start using recompose, lot of things still magic for me ))
I hope some on can help me, pass several days to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are problems in composed component.

There's no `bookNode` and event handlers on `this`. `App` is stateless component that doesn't have access to `this`, `bookNode` and event handlers are props.

It isn't `value` that is passed to *state* handlers, it's `state`, as the name suggests.

It should be:

```
const stateHandlers = {
    handleTouchStart: state => () => ({
        value: state.value + 1
    }),
    handleTouchEnd: state => () => ({
        value: state.value - 1
    })
};

export const enhance = compose(
    setDisplayName("App"),
    withProps(props => ({
        bookNode: React.createRef()
    })),
    withStateHandlers(state, stateHandlers),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.bookNode.current.ontouchstart = this.props.handleTouchStart;
            this.props.bookNode.current.ontouchend = this.props.handleTouchEnd;
        }
    })
);

export const App = ({ value, bookNode }) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Value: {value}</h3>
        <button ref={bookNode}>Submit</button>
    </div>
);
```

Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uyd6lu).

Usually there's no reason to access DOM manually to set up events because React handles this. This eliminates the need for a ref and lifecycle hooks:

```
export const enhance = compose(
    setDisplayName("App"),
    withStateHandlers(state, stateHandlers)
);

const App = ({ value, handleTouchStart, handleTouchEnd }) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Value: {value}</h3>
        <button onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}>Submit</button>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: In my situation i need to prevent default onTouchStart. But in Google Chrome they takes away .preventDefoult() method in 56 version and above. More information here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9809#issuecomment-413978405    https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention